# SQLite Field definitions

Tags: sqlite, field

I am just starting out in the world of SQLite and am looking at the field definitions,
Am I correct in thinking that there seems to be no difference between `Varchar` / `Char` and `text` fields in SQLite? Also does setting the field length have any affect?

```
CompanyName varchar (40) NOT NULL ,
```

And Finally if I were to give a default value to a boolean field would I use `1` or `True` as the default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I correct in thinking that there seems to be no difference between
>   Varchar / Char and text fields in sQLite?

Yes you are correct. They are all the same to sqlite.

> Also does setting the field length have any affect?

Also correct; note that nothing stops an upper layer from doing some form of checking/enforcing of the length.

> if I were to give a default value to a boolean field would I use 1 or
>   True as the default?

1 (or any non-zero numeric value) as demonstrated in the following:

```
sqlite> select 1 where True;
Error: no such column: True
sqlite> select 1 where 1;
1
sqlite> select 1 where "True";
sqlite> select 1 where "False";
sqlite> select 1 where 0;
sqlite> select 1 where -1;
1
```

**Remarks about true/false with sqlite**

SQLite expresses true with 1 and false with 0:

```
sqlite> select 3 > 2;
1
sqlite> select 3 < 2;
0
```

What SQLite considers to be true or false is more complicated. I'll just quote the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#booleanexpr):

> To convert the results of an SQL expression to a boolean value, SQLite
>   first casts the result to a NUMERIC value in the same way as a CAST
>   expression. A NULL or zero value (integer value 0 or real value 0.0)
>   is considered to be false. All other values are considered true.
>
> For example, the values NULL, 0.0, 0, 'english' and '0' are all
>   considered to be false. Values 1, 1.0, 0.1, -0.1 and '1english' are
>   considered to be true.